# How to Explain "efficient frontier" to child?

Tags: technical-analysis

I have found this challenge almost impossible because I don't want to use too technical jargon, just nice pictures, gestures and analogies to everyday life. So I created this pathological example with monkey A and B. Monkey A is believes that reserving a variety of food such as bananas, mangos and kiwis will result in lower risk shown with first curved frontier.

x-axis would be technically standard deviation but you can suppose it is a risk to lose food from the average, y-axis the amount of editable food.

Can you find any argument, rather than some Python lines, to support one of the models? What kind of monkeys are A and B?

**Monkey A`s view**

[image]

Monkey B only believes in the Banana so gathers only them. It is a bit risky endeavour because they stale at the same speed and there are times when B hits almost 0 bananas but then again there are times when B hits a huge amount of bananas during harvest, much more than A can ever imagine. B won't even try the next best alternative, mocking mangos and such things in trees being too inferior. How to explain this kind of monkey what an `efficient frontier` is and when B's view is totally correct or incorrect?

**Monkey B`s view**

[image]

**Related**

- the odd holes in the frontier and floating point err, more [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/30367/odd-fractal-looking-illusion-with-x-y-z-in-0-1-such-that-xyz-1-what-is)

Comment: Dude - I'm not surprised the child is lost as I know I'm lost. Regardless, how old is the child you are teaching? - no answer will be possible without that basic piece of information.

Comment: +1 for a very well formed analogy, but it took me a while to understand the purpose of the analogy :)

Comment: @gef05: you can suppose there is a bunch of them with different ages. I don't want to specify the age, I don't like age discrimination. The below model does not take into account the correlation between the items. It is just a naive sum-product with different data points, a thing easy to explain anyone knowing a bit of multiplication, addition and averages. It is a crucial model where correlation plays no role, only proportions must add to 1. The next model is a bit advanced and requires some statistical measures but it is crucial to get into diversification. Lost without the jargon though.

Comment: @hhh I gave you a +1 as well for effort, but it is much too complicated and I think you are using the wrong graph technique.  I don't think a child can really think in terms of 3D graphs.

Comment: I think this is off-topic. If this applies to finance then please rephrase the question.

Comment: @hhh. I don't know what you mean by age discrimination. What I do know, as a former educator, is that basic pedagogy requires knowledge of the student - including age. No one answer will be correct. Your approach for teaching a ten-year old will differ vastly from that for a 15-year old (for example). I'll gladly bring 20 years of experience to the question if you can provide necessary guidance. :)

Comment: @Vitalik: suppose bananas were a fund A, Kiwis fund B and mangos fund C(or any other choices). Now try to explain efficient frontier to a random walker you may meet on the street, it is not just child to whom it can be hard to explain: [diversificication](http://money.stackexchange.com/questions/7304/is-there-such-a-thing-as-over-diversification) revisited (again) and sad [research](http://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=529062) about private investors. This kind of issues are very local, personal and are financial, perhaps day-work of some analysts. How with eff.frontier?

Comment: @gef05: I don't like that people mock the inability of children. If a child is very young, it requires skilled instructor and/or motivated child -- stereotypical cases to dogs. I have actually explained this issue to adults and children alike. Nothing beats horror-coding/popcorn -sessions to formal financial meetings. What do you think about my plan to explain efficient frontier to a child? Please, see my answer. I have tried to lower the technical barrier by offering code to play with and make it clear that it is no money-issue to find the efficient portfolio. It just requires some time.

Comment: @Ralph Winters: thank you for the point. Sorry about the poor graph, fast OpenOffice -thing. What do you think about my 2D and 3D graphs in my answer?

Comment: @hhh. No problems, mate. Looks like others are offering what you seek. All the best,

Comment: @hhh I think it is a lot better. Can you annotate where the optimal risk/reward point is?  How would you explain that there really isn't any right choice, but that everything is a tradeoff.

Comment: @Ralph Winters: Pardon. Sorry but I would watch out for dangerous generalizations like "everything is a tradeoff" because it in itself is a topic on its own. I would try to stick to frontiers, scale them to more funds, test different distributions, show examples -- good topic -- already faced floating point oddities [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/30367/odd-fractal-looking-illusion-with-x-y-z-in-0-1-such-that-xyz-1-what-is), design-issues (see more "Related").

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would let them get their hands dirty, learn by practicing. Below you can find a simple program to generate your own efficient frontier, just 29 lines' python. Depending on the age, adult could help in the activity but I would not make it too lecturing. With child-parent relationship, I would make it a challenge, no easy money anymore -- let-your-money work-for-you -attitude, create the efficient portfolio!

[image]

If there are many children, I would do a competition over years' time-span or make many small competitions. Winner is the one whose portfolio is closest to some efficient portfolio such as lowest-variance-portfolio, I have the code to calculate things like that but it is trivial so build on the code below. Because the efficient frontier is a good way to let participants to investigate different returns and risk between assets classes like stocks, bonds and money, I would make the thing more serious. The winner could get his/her designed portfolio (to keep it fair in your budget, you could limit choices to index funds starting with 1EUR investment or to ask bottle-price-participation-fee, bring me a bottle and you are in. No money issue.).

Since they probably don't have much money, I would choose free software.

*Have fun!*

**Step-by-step instructions for your own Efficient Frontier**

2. Copy and run the Python script with `$ python simple.py > .datSimple`
3. Plot the data with `$ gnuplot -e "set ylabel 'Return'; set xlabel 'Risk'; set terminal png; set output 'yourEffFrontier.png'; plot '.datSimple'"` or any spreadsheet program.
4. Your first "assets" could well be low-risk candies and some easy-to-stale products like bananas -- but beware, notice the PS.

[image]

**Simple Efficient-frontier generator**

```
#Author: hhh
#License: ISC license

global profit, stdDev, correlation

profit = [0.25,0.2]
stdDev= [0.2,0.15]
correlation = [[1,-0.5],[-0.5,1]]

def portfolioReturn(a,b):
   return profit[0]*a+profit[1]*b

def portfolioStdDev(a,b):
   variance=0
   values=[a,b]

   for i in range(2):
      for j in range(2):
         variance = variance + values[i]*values[j]*stdDev[i]*stdDev[j]*correlation[i][j]

   return (variance)**(0.5)

def main():
   for x in [h/100.0 for h in range(100)]:
      y=1-x
      if abs(x+y-1)<1e-10:
         print "%s\t%s"%(str(portfolioStdDev(x,y)), str(portfolioReturn(x,y)))

main()
```

*P.s. do not stagnate with collectibles, such as candies and toys, and retailer products, such as mangos, because they are not really good "investments" per se, a bit more like speculation. The retailer gets a huge percentage, for further information consult Bogleheads.org like [here](http://www.bogleheads.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=63623&sid=5c44b44b19d894a16fb3cc51401b4610) about collectible items.*

Answer (score 3):

I know you really like bananas, but don't you think you would get tired of them after a while?  Better stock up on some kiwi and mango just to mix it up a bit.

I wouldn't want to risk eating only banana sandwiches, banana ice cream and banana bread for the rest of my life.  I have don't think I could take it.  Same goes for mango and kiwi, but I think if I had all three I could probably get along just fine.

Comment: wait, how old is this kid?

Comment: I'm going to start downvoting posts that make me hungry